How to upload multiple file attach in laravel email
My listing page each record has checkbox now i choose one or more record to click send email db to featch records filename to pass email?is it possible?
i need to select record files attach email
Controller
$formList = is_array($request->selected_users) ? $request->selected_users : explode(',', $request->selected_users);
        $filenames = [];
        foreach ($formList as $id) {
            $record = record::find($id);
            $filenames[] = $record->filename;
        }

Mail class
foreach ($files as $file) {
            if (!empty($file) && file_exists($file) && is_readable($file) && strlen($file) > 0) {
                 $message->attach($file);
                $message->attachFromStorage($file);
            } else {
                echo "Error: File $file is empty or does not exist\n";
            }
        }

Error:
{message: "Cannot access offset of type string on string", exception: "TypeError",…}


 public function sendSelectedRecordsEmail(Request $request)
{
    $selectedRecordIds = $request->input('selected_records', []);
    $records = Record::whereIn('id', $selectedRecordIds)->get();

    $attachments = [];

    foreach ($records as $record) {
        // Assuming 'file_path' is the attribute containing the file path
        $attachments[] = storage_path('app/' . $record->file_path);
    }

    // Send email with attachments
    Mail::to('premodsuraweera@gmail.com')
        ->send(new SendMultipleFiles($attachments));

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Email sent successfully with selected records.');
}

I used this function and it worked

Could you please send Mail class function code
